# read file into array separated by paragraph Python

Tags: python, arrays, parsing

I have a text file, I want to read this text file into 3 different arrays, array1 array2 and array3. the first paragraph gets put in array1, the second paragraph gets put in array2 and so on. the 4th paragraph will then be put in array1 element2 and so forth, paragraphs are separated by a blank line. any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the basic code I would try:

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')

data = f.read()
array1 = []
array2 = []
array3 = []
splat = data.split("\n\n")
for number, paragraph in enumerate(splat, 1):
    if number % 3 == 1:
        array1 += [paragraph]
    elif number % 3 == 2:
        array2 += [paragraph]
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        array3 += [paragraph]
```

This should be enough to get you started. If the paragraphs in the file are split by two new lines then "\n\n" should do the trick for splitting them.

Comment: `with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:` would be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

```
import itertools as it


def paragraphs(fileobj, separator='\n'):
    """Iterate a fileobject by paragraph"""
    ## Makes no assumptions about the encoding used in the file
    lines = []
    for line in fileobj:
        if line == separator and lines:
            yield ''.join(lines)
            lines = []
        else:
            lines.append(line)
    yield ''.join(lines)

paragraph_lists = [[], [], []]
with open('/Users/robdev/Desktop/test.txt') as f:
    paras = paragraphs(f)
    for para, group in it.izip(paras, it.cycle(paragraph_lists)):
        group.append(para)

print paragraph_lists
```

Comment: Huge plus for using a streaming state machine approach to splitting text by paragraph! This should be the preferred solution rather than simply split("\n\n") which has many suboptimal edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked long before but just putting my inputs so that it will be useful to somebody else at some point of time. 
I got to know much easier way to split the input file into paragraphs based on the Paragraph Separator(it can be a \n or a blank space or anything else) and the code snippet for your question is given below :

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as input:
    input_ = input.read().split("\n\n")   #\n\n denotes there is a blank line in between paragraphs.
```

And after executing this command, if you try to print input_[0] it will show the first paragraph, input_[1] will show the second paragraph and so on. So it is putting all the paragraphs present in the input file into an List with each List element contains a paragraph from the input file.

Answer (score 2):

This code will search for lines between two points:

```py
rr = [] #Array for saving lines    
for f in file_list:
    with open(f, 'rt') as fl:
        lines = fl.read()
        lines = lines[lines.find('String1'):lines.find('String2')] 
        rr.append(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I feel like showing off:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    f = list(f)
    a, b, c = (list(__import__('itertools').islice(f, i, None, 3)) for i in range(3))
```

Comment: That doesn't split the content of the file; The islice objects will iterate lines in the file.

Comment: Each one is an iterator over a subset of lines in the file, which is then explicitly converted into a `list`. What's the problem? Edit: tested and found that everything ends up in the first iterator, for reasons I don't understand. This is fixed by reading from a list instead of a stream (which is what I tested originally); edited accordingly.

Comment: Yeah. OP wants to iterate paragraphs, not lines

Comment: Follow-up: the problem occurs because each `islice` attempts to read the stream fully before the next gets to operate. Annoying; there ought to be a more elegant way to multiplex a stream. @Rob "paragraphs" are normally defined by newlines in text files; if the lines of text are explicitly wrapped then the OP needs to say so, and identify exactly what separates paragraphs.

Comment: I'd say paragraphs are usually separated by a blank line, so two newlines '\n\n'. There may be (and are likely to be) more than one line (and hence newline chars) within a paragraph. So simple line-based iteration is not enough. Anyway, the `islice` issues is an interesting one.

Comment: If we take `\n\n` as our separator, then reading the file into a list of paragraphs is as simple as `f.read().split('\n\n')`. Although given that the streaming thing doesn't work right, there's no longer a point to it; it would be better to just use list slices.

Answer (score 0):

Using slices would also work.

```
par_separator = "\n\n"
paragraphs = "1\n\n2\n\n3\n\n4\n\n5\n\n6".split(par_separator)
a,b,c = paragraphs[0:len(paragraphs):3], paragraphs[1:len(paragraphs):3],\
        paragraphs[2:len(paragraphs):3]
```

Within slice: [start index, end index,step]

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way to bypass slices:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for p in grouper(5,[sent.strip() for sent in text.split('\n') if sent !='']):
    print p
```

Just make sure you deal with None in final text