# Python how to read text paragraph by paragraph

Tags: python, iterator

I'm a Python beginner and I'm trying to read the example.txt file paragraph by paragraph using the **iterator** and **next** methods. The problem is, I cannot figure out how to read line by line in the next method without using a for loop or line = next(it). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have until now.

```
class ByParagraph:


    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text


    def __iter__(self):
        return self
        par = ""


    def __next__(self):
        par = ""
        if (I still need to decide how to stop the iterations):
            raise StopIteration

        if str(self.text).isspace():
            return par.strip()
        else:
            return ' '.join([par, str(self.text)])



with open("example.txt") as f:
    for par in ByParagraph(f):
        print('BEGIN PAR' + par + 'END PAR')
```

Comment: Can you describe how its going wrong? I'd imagine that you would probably want to keep reading lines in `__next__` until you hit a line which contains only `\n`. It might actually be easier to just use a generator function, or is the point to learn to use iterators?

Comment: `nltk` has this functionality built-in

Comment: @PaulRooney yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Read the lines in __next __ I always use a loop, but I don't think I have to do that in the method... and yes, that's the point, but I've tried lots of things without a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read file into array separated by paragraph Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282970/read-file-into-array-separated-by-paragraph-python)

Comment: @Tagc it's different. I'm trying to solve this problem in a specific way. I already did it the way the other person suggests. But that is not my question

Comment: @Sofia My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to actually consume `self.text` because this is a file iterator (`f`), i.e. you need to call `next(self.text)`. You need to call this multiple times to consume all the lines until you receive a blank like, so you need a loop. A `for` loop will call `next(self.text)` so this should work, e.g.:

```
def __next__(self):
    par = []
    for line in self.text:
        if line.isspace():
            break
        par.append(line.strip())
    else:
        if not par:
            raise StopIteration()
    return ' '.join(par)
```

The `for` loop will cleanly exit on `StopIteration` so will enter the `else` clause. You should raise `StopIteration` only if there is no `par` to avoid missing the last paragraph.

Comment: oh thank you! : D For some reason I was expecting not to need a loop in the __next__ method..